# M2 not showing up on BIOS

Tags: ssd

2.5 Years ago I had a computer built for me, and noone told me that SSDs have a limited life. I don't know if it is dead but BIOS can't see it anymore. It had windows on it, and because I held the wrong belief that SSDs are better at preserving things than HDDs, I put everything important on my m2. Every mp3, every wav and every music project ever. Now after I booted my computer yesterday, it bluescreened (didn't see what failed). And if I try to boot it up, it tells me to select a proper boot device.
Is there a fix, any chance that my m2 isn't dead? If my m2 died, can I somehow get my data back?

Comment: Any electrical component can fail. While it is likely that the SSD has failed it is possible that the computer or other parts of the computer have failed. It may be worth your while to put the SSD in a USB enclosure to see if it still works on another PC. If it doesn't then it may be time to send it to a data recovery specialist, though those can be quite pricey.

Comment: SSDs are not all created equal. A high quality SSD is good beyond 5 years of normal use. Truly as good or better than hard drives.